# Simple docker container for NGINX with volumes

Tags: docker, nginx

everyone.

Making my first steps with Docker and want to build an NGINX server, where all the configuration files, logs, and web data will be placed on volumes.

Here is my docker-compose.yml.

I expected that all the configuration files from the /etc/nginx, including conf.d file, will be copied to my NGINX volume.

I also created WWW/html/ directory with a custom index.html to replace the standard welcome page.

```
  version: '3.7'
    
    services:
    
        nginx:
            image: nginx
            ports:
                - "80:80"
            volumes:
    
                # nginx configs
                - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
    
                # projects folder
                - ./WWW:/var/www
    
                # nginx logs
                - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
    
            restart: always
```

But somehow this does not work. Where I was work?

Answer (score 0):

When you mount a directory you override (technically hide, you can still access the real folder in the container) the mount destination with your source. It won't fill your dirs. If you want to extract the contents of those directories, temporarely disable the mounts and use command `docker cp`. More info in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)